# dynamically binding a model in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an admin portal that I am trying to create, and in it I have custom endpoints specific to a given client.

So for instance, for one client, the admin/our-staff page would redirect internally to the admin/team-members page, because our-staff is a page that follows the team-members template. However, the customer gets to choose their endpoint named admin/our-staff, so there's no way to do this statically.

In my RouteConfig.cs I have:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "adminPageRoute",
            "admin/pages/{page}/{action2}",
            new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", page = "", action2 = "" }
            );
```

Then in my PageController.cs I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(string page, string action2)
{
    var pageData = ...

    //  Grabbing from database a map between page variable and PageType 
    // depending on Session's User ID

    if (pageData.PageType == 1)
    {
        return TeamMembers();
    }

    else return View("Index");

}

public ActionResult TeamMembers()
{
    TeamMemberModel model = ???;
}
```

The question is, how do I generate this model? Normally I can just put the TeamMemberModel param in the action method as a parameter and MVC will automatically fill it out for me. But since it's getting called directly from another method, I get a compile error obviously if I try something like this:

```
public ActionResult TeamMembers(TeamMemberModel model)
{
}
```

I could manually map this one model from the Request's HTTPContext, but I'd really rather not do that for all of the models that I plan on having. Is there any way to dynamically trigger the binding and form a new instance of the model without a controller method? Any help greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**
It ended up being something simple. Answer posted here for future reference

```
public ActionResult TeamMembers()
{
    TeamMemberModel model = new TeamMemberModel();
    this.UpdateModel<TeamMemberModel>(model);
}
```

Comment: Note that viewmodel class you have should initialized first since it's not `static`: `TeamMemberModel model = new TeamMemberModel();`. The compiler error may related to usage of uninitialized class when used in controller action method.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but perhaps I wasn't clear in that the problem isn't that I'm getting a compiler error, it is that I do not know how to get the Model from the HTTP Request object. I am now exploring options with UpdateModel that might work

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being something simple. Answer posted here for future reference

```
public ActionResult TeamMembers()
{
    TeamMemberModel model = new TeamMemberModel();
    this.UpdateModel<TeamMemberModel>(model);
}
```